# Moq tests using ExpectSet() with It.Is<T>() aren't behaving as... expected

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, mocking, moq

I've isolated the behaviour into the following test case. I'd be grateful to anyone who can tell me how to expect/verify a property set for a `List<T>` property - it appears there's something going on inside `It.Is<T>(predicate)` that isn't making a whole lot of sense to me right now. Sample code will run as a console app from VS2008 - you'll need to add a reference to Moq 2.6 (I'm on 2.6.1014.1) - please try uncommenting the different ExpectSet statements to see what's happening...

```
using System;
using Moq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MoqDemo {

    public interface IView {
        List<string> Names { get; set; }
    }

    public class Controller {
        private IView view;

        public Controller(IView view) {
            this.view = view;
        }

        public void PopulateView() {
            List<string> names = new List<string>() { "Hugh", "Pugh", "Barney McGrew" };
            view.Names = names;
        }

        public class MyApp {
            public static void Main() {
                Mock<IView> mockView = new Mock<IView>();

                // This works - and the expectation is verifiable.
                mockView.ExpectSet(mv => mv.Names);

                // None of the following can be verified.
                // mockView.ExpectSet(mv => mv.Names, It.Is<Object>(o => o != null));
                // mockView.ExpectSet(mv => mv.Names, It.Is<List<string>>(names => names.Count == 3));
                // mockView.ExpectSet(mv => mv.Names, It.IsAny<IList<String>>());

                Controller controller = new Controller(mockView.Object);
                controller.PopulateView();
                try {
                    mockView.VerifyAll();
                    Console.WriteLine("Verified OK!");
                } catch (MockException ex) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Verification failed!");
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
                Console.ReadKey(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not using the very latest version of Moq, so I don't have an overload of ExpectSet that takes two parameters, but I've had some success with this pattern:

```
mockView.ExpectSet(mv => mv.Names).Callback(n => Assert.That(n != null));
```

The Assert (from NUnit) call in the callback will throw an exception if the value assigned to .Names doesn't match the predicate. It does make it hard to trace when a test fails, though. I agree that the ability to pass an It.Is or It.IsAny as the second parameter would be handy.

Comment: There is no such overload - even in the latest version - but the callback syntax there is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of ExpectSet() is the value you're expecting. You can't use `It.Is<T>` in this case as there's no overload that takes a predicate - though it would be nice ;) Here's a (simplified) excerpt from your sample, illustrating the use of a value:

```
var mockView = new Mock<IView>();
var list = new List<string> { "Hugh", "Pugh", "Barney McGrew" };

mockView.ExpectSet(mv => mv.Names, list);

mockView.Object.Names = list;
```

Hope that helps.

Edit: fixed typo.

Answer (score 1):

BTW, It.Is is not supported on ExpectSet. Your code compiles just because they are regular method invocations when used as values (as opposed to expressions), whereas when used in an Expect *expression* they are pre-processed by Moq and given specific meaning (rather than the null/default value that all It.Is members actually return).

You could use the stub behavior on the given property (mockView.Stub(mv => mv.Names)) and later assert directly for its value after execution.

Answer (score 0):

Moq doesn't provide an overload receiving It.IsAny as it's effectively the same as calling ExpectSet without passing an expected value ;)